# ByteSwapping Java Floats to use for C++ program

Tags: java, floating-point, endianness

I have to convert a series of Java floats into Little Endian to be correctly read by a C++ program. I am working with a large amount of floats.

I have tried ByteBuffer, GeoSoft, and the Apache Commons I/O utilities. About every 1% of the time, some of the floats, when converted to IntBits, seem to be recognized as an NaN value. I've even tried FLOAT.floatToRawIntBits to solve the problem, but to no avail.

As an example of what I'm talking about, I am giving a specific instance when the problem arises.

Here are a series of floats which are correctly swapped..

```
8.93516466e-02
-1.0571138
-2.2298267
0.042286094
0.8592236
0.5098497
0.67256117
```

However, I am seeing this:

```
6.9055E-41
-1.0571138
-2.2298267
0.042286094
0.8592236
0.5098497
0.67256117
```

Can you please tell me how I can 'absorb' these sequences of Bits recognized as NaN?

I am pasting the code that I used to facilitate the byte swap.

```
 public static float swap (float value)
  {
    int intValue = Float.floatToRawIntBits (value);
    intValue = swap (intValue);
    return Float.intBitsToFloat (intValue);
  }

 public static int swap (int value)
  {
    int b1 = (value >>  0) & 0xff;
    int b2 = (value >>  8) & 0xff;
    int b3 = (value >> 16) & 0xff;
    int b4 = (value >> 24) & 0xff;
    return b1 << 24 | b2 << 16 | b3 << 8 | b4 << 0;
  }
```

The problem number in this case is 8.93516466e-02

I printed out the bits before and after the swap and got this:

```
111101101101101111110111111111
11111111111111011011011000111101
```

This was my code to print this out -- tell me if it is wrong:

```
public static float testSwap (float value)
{
    int intValue = Float.floatToRawIntBits (value);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(intValue));
    intValue = swap (intValue);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(intValue));
        return Float.intBitsToFloat (intValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact bit patterns for the sample values you posted? If you could do this for the first one, for both the Java side (before swapping) and the C++ side, it would be particularly helpful.

Comment: @TedHopp I'll try and figure out how to do that lol.. As a clarification, you want the 1s and 0s right? I don't have access to the C++ program itself. However, I will show you what I input into the swapper, and what comes out of the swapper. Correct me if you wanted something else -- I am not too well-versed in the language of computer programming.

Comment: @TedHopp I printed out the bit patterns. Please tell me if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Either the hex or binary, with the most significant bit or hex digit to the left.

Comment: I think I got what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a float into another float by swapping the bytes.  You must have the original `int` value or some values will be corrupted as you have seen.  This is because float will normalise its values and not all bit patterns are valid in Java.

I suggest reading using ByteBuffer for FloatBuffer in native byte order.  This way you will not be corrupting you values.

Comment: I have a question: what is the difference between using FloatBuffer versus the general ByteBuffer? When I tried using ByteBuffer, I had the same problems. Specifically, what about FloatBuffer uniquely solves this issue? I am not asking this because I doubt your method. Rather, I just want to know more about it. I am reading the source code too.

I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: @newproduct if you had a problem with ByteBuffer or FloatBuffer it is because you were not setting the byte order with `.order(ByteOrder.LITTE_ENDIAN)` and you were trying to do it incorrectly yourself.